# Html: scrollable div with fixed background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get a full-screen image background with a scrollable div on its center, so I wrote this code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Bio</title>
<link href="../css/layout-base.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).ready(function(){
        var background = $('#background');
        var scrollable = $('#scrollable-container');
        var halfWhite = $('#halfWhite');
        var halfBlack = $('#halfBlack');
        /* calcolo dimensione finestra */
        var maxWidth = $(window).width();
        var maxHeight = $(window).height();

        /* settaggio dimensioni immagine sfondo */
        background.css("height",maxHeight);
        background.css("width",maxWidth);

        scrollable.css("height",maxHeight);

        /* settaggio dimensioni riempimento sfondo */
        halfWhite.css("height",maxHeight);
        halfWhite.css("width",maxWidth/2);
        halfBlack.css("height",maxHeight);
        halfBlack.css("width",maxWidth/2);
    });
    $(window).resize(function(){
        var background = $('#background');
        var scrollable = $('#scrollable-container');
        var halfWhite = $('#halfWhite');
        var halfBlack = $('#halfBlack');
        /* calcolo dimensione finestra */
        var maxWidth = $(window).width();
        var maxHeight = $(window).height();

        /* settaggio dimensioni immagine sfondo */
        background.css("height",maxHeight);
        background.css("width",maxWidth);

        scrollable.css("height",maxHeight);

        /* settaggio dimensioni riempimento sfondo */
        halfWhite.css("height",maxHeight);
        halfWhite.css("width",maxWidth/2);
        halfBlack.css("height",maxHeight);
        halfBlack.css("width",maxWidth/2);
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="background">
    <div id="halfWhite"></div>
    <div id="halfBlack"></div>
    <div id="scrollable-container">
        <div class="content">
            <div id="text"></div>
            <a href="#" class="menu" id="home" target="_self"><img src="../media/index/tasto1.png"/></a>
            <a href="#" class="menu" id="events" target="_self"><img src="../media/index/tasto2.png"/></a>
            <a href="#" class="menu" id="gallery" target="_self"><img src="../media/index/tasto3.png"/></a>
            <a href="#" class="menu" id="disco" target="_self"><img src="../media/index/tasto4.png"/></a>
        </div><!--div content -->
    </div>
</div><!-- div background -->
</body>
</html>
```

With the relative css:

```
body{
overflow:hidden;
margin:0!important;
}
#background{
background-image:url(../media/index/back.png);
background-size:contain;
background-position:center;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
 #halfWhite{
position:relative;
background-color: white;
z-index: -10;
float: left;
}
#halfBlack{
position:relative;
background-color: black;
z-index: -10;
float: right;
}
#scrollable-container{margin-left: 15%;margin-right: 15%;background-    color:rgba(0,0,0,0.00);}
.content{
height:98%;
position: relative;
top:1%;
padding-left: 15%;
padding-right: 15%;
box-shadow: -10px 2px 15px #dedede,10px -2px  15px #dedede;
-moz-box-shadow:-10px 2px 15px #dedede,10px -2px  15px #dedede;
-webkit-box-shadow:-10px 2px 15px #dedede,10px -2px  15px #dedede;
background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
}
#text{position:absolute;top:10%;width:100%;height:100000px;width:70%}
.menu{
width:15%;
-webkit-transition: all 0.4s linear;
-moz-transition: all 0.4s linear;
-o-transition: all 0.4s linear;
-ms-transition: all 0.4s linear;
transition: all 0.4s linear;
}
.menu:hover{
-webkit-transform: scale(0.85,0.85);
-moz-transform: scale(0.85,0.85);
-o-transform: scale(0.85,0.85);
-ms-transform: scale(0.85,0.85);
transform: scale(0.85,0.85);
}
.menu img{width:100%}
#home{position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;}
#events{position:absolute;top:0px;right:0px;}
#gallery{position:absolute;bottom:0px;left:0px;}
#disco{position:absolute;bottom:0px;right:0px;}
```

I want the #text div to scroll while the rest of the page has to stay fixed (so that the background is always on the same position), but when I add overflow property to the parent divs there are strange side effects (for example, the .content div goes to the very bottom of the page).
How can I achieve this behaviour? Is this the correct way to make this kind of layout?

Answer (score 0):

You need to place your background first in your html and give it a property of position: fixed. Then the rest of your html needs to go on top without the fixed property.

Answer (score 0):

make this `#text` div `style="position:fixed"` and the rest parts with `position:absolute`.